# JavaScript confusion with closure while trying to create private function

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

I'm trying to create a class like way of accessing objects with public and private functions/variables, but I'm a little confused as to why this simple test code doesn't work.

```js
// Class type object with just one value.

function Play(arg) { // Constructor.
    var test = arg;

// Private, as not declared with "this." Obviously more complex in the future.
    private_settest = function( val ) {
        test = val;
    }

// Public.
    this.settest = function( val ) {
        private_settest(val);
    }

    this.gettest = function() {
        return test;
    }
}

var a = new Play(1);
var b = new Play(2);
a.settest(100);
console.log(a.gettest());
console.log(b.gettest());
```

I'd expect the output to be 1 2 but the actual output is 1 100.

I believe this to be a closure issue, anyone care to explain what I'm missing?

When stepping through this.settest():
The closure value of test is 1 (this is correct).

When stepping into private_settest():
The closure value of test is 2. This is wrong, it should be 1.

On stepping out of private_settest() the closure value is back to 1 again. I guess this is the closure being popped.

Help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: `private_settest = function( val )
    {
        test = val;
    }` should be `function private_settest( val )
    {
        test = val;
    }`

Comment: By the way, wouldn't you expect the output to be 100 2?

Comment: Always use strict mode!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private_settest = function(val) {
    test = val;
}
```

This implicitly defines a global variable `private_settest`, and when you construct `new Play()`, the global is overwritten each time, referencing the scope of the last initialized instance of `Play`, in this case `b`. That is why the "private" function accesses the second instance's scope, as you have observed. This should be changed to

```
function private_settest(val) {
    test = val;
}
```

in order to correctly declare a function within each instance's scope.

```js
// Class type object with just one value.

function Play(arg) { // Constructor.
  var test = arg;

  // Private, as not declared with "this." Obviously more complex in the future.
  function private_settest(val) {
    test = val;
  }

  // Public.
  this.settest = function(val) {
    private_settest(val);
  }

  this.gettest = function() {
    return test;
  }
}

var a = new Play(1);
var b = new Play(2);
a.settest(100);
console.log(a.gettest());
console.log(b.gettest());
```

This produces the expected output 100 2 (not 1 2).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `private_settest` is a global variable. You did not use `var` (`let`, `const` or `function`) to declare that function variable with local scope. So every time you call the constructor the previous version of that function is overwritten.

When you then call `a.setttest`, you actually (via the method) call that single global function that modifies the private variable `test` which really is the private variable of the `b` instance (the last one that was created).

If you would have used `"use strict"`, you would have received an error message about this.